# Parallel.ForEach in recursive method

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a method that collect shares information and write results to database,
I use Parallel.Foreach which increased the performance especially if scanning 100 TB

If i run this code in my local database, i have no issues, but on the sandbox database i got tons of exceptions / innerExceptions

Code:

```
private static INodeCollection NodesLookUp(string path, int maximumLevel)
       {

           var shareCollectionNode = new ShareCollection(path);
           shareCollectionNode.GetNodeProperties();
           shareCollectionNode.GetPermissionEntires();
           WriteNodeToDatabase(shareCollectionNode); // write collected infomation to database
           if (maximumLevel <= 0 && _maximumSubLevels != -1)
           {
               return shareCollectionNode;
           }

           Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetDirectories(shareCollectionNode.FullPath), directory =>
           {
              try
             {
                  lock (shareCollectionNode)
                  {
                      shareCollectionNode.AddNode(NodesLookUp(directory, maximumLevel - 1));
                  }

              }
              catch (UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedAccessException)
              {
                  lock (_shareIssues)
                  {
                      _shareIssues.Add(new ShareIssue(TraceStatu.UnauthorizedAccess, directory,
                     unauthorizedAccessException.Message, dfsId, currentLevel));
                  }

               }

           });

           return shareCollectionNode;
       }
```

Writing to database:

```
private static void WriteNodeToDatabase(ShareCollection shareCollection)
    {
        var nodeId = Persistence.UpsertShare(shareCollection);
        var sharePermissions = new List<IPermissionRight>();
        foreach (var permissionEntry in shareCollection.PermissionEntries)
        {
            permissionEntry.NodeId = nodeId;
            var permissionEntryId = Persistence.InsertPermissionEntry(permissionEntry);
            permissionEntry.SetPermissions(permissionEntryId);
            sharePermissions.AddRange(permissionEntry.Permissions);
        }
        Persistence.InsertPermissions(sharePermissions);
    }
```

Exceptions:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If i remove the Parallel.Foreach and use normal for loop then i have no issue beside that the application takes ages to run.

Comment: Please format the code in a way that removes or at least reduces the need to scroll horizontaly.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` that ends up with a `lock`?

Comment: This is what I don't like about Pokemon exception handling: we have no idea where this exception is being thrown from. Any idea which query is causing this error?

Comment: You've posted **a lot of code**, but I have to say that based on the error none of it is very relevant. I'm pretty sure we need to see `Persistence.InsertPermissions`.

Comment: Thanks all, it is my first time to write a code using Parallel, i didn't know where the issue is, but i recreated the database and it's solved by modifing the storedprocedure. you were all right the issue was in the database level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try replacing this

```
lock (shareCollectionNode)
{
    shareCollectionNode.AddNode(NodesLookUp(directory, maximumLevel - 1));
}
```

with this

```
var node = NodesLookUp(directory, maximumLevel - 1);
lock (shareCollectionNode)
{
    shareCollectionNode.AddNode(node);
}
```

and the same for second lock.

Although it's a better way to achieve what you want by paralleling, also it may help to reproduce the same errors locally, as it should increase database activity.

The actual issue I think relies on DataBase transactions - looks like during concurrent database operations result in intermediate results in tables which returns not valid data; I cannot say more until we see actual queries and table schema.